# Using Guice's @SessionScoped with Netty

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, netty

How do I implement @SessionScoped in a Netty based TCP server? Creating [Custom Scopes](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes) is documented in Guice manual, but it seems that the solution only works for thread based and not asynchronous IO servers.

Is it enough to create the *Channel Pipeline* between `scope.enter()` and `scope.exit()`?

Comment: Does Netty support "sessions objects"? It looks the Channel.getId() is the Netty alike. So you could use the [example](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes) and switch the ThreadLocal out for a map of <Integer<Map<Key<?>, Object>>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer : this answer is for Netty 3. I've not had the opportunity to try Netty 4 yet, so I don't know if what follows can be applied to the newer version.

Netty is asynchronous on the network side, but unless you explicity submit tasks to Executors, or change threads by any other means, the handling of `ChannelEvent`s by the `ChannelHandler`s on a pipeline is synchronous and sequential. For instance, if you use Netty 3 and have an `ExecutionHandler` on the pipeline, the scope handler should be upstream of the `ExecutionHandler`; for Netty 4, see Trustin Lee's comment.

Thus, you can put a handler near the beginning of your pipeline that manages the session scope, for example:

```
public class ScopeHandler implements ChannelUpstreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent e) {

        if (e instanceof WriteCompletionEvent || e instanceof ExceptionEvent)
            ctx.sendUpstream(e);

        Session session = ...; // get session, presumably using e.getChannel()

        scope.enter();
        try {
            scope.seed(Key.get(Session.class), session);
            ctx.sendUpstream(e);
        }
        finally {
            scope.exit();
        }
    }

    private SessionScope scope;

}
```

A couple of quick remarks:

- You will want to filter some event types out, especially `WriteCompletionEvent` and `ExceptionEvent` which the framework will put at the downstream end of the pipeline during event processing and wil cause reentrancy issues if not excluded. In our application, we use this kind of handler but actually only consider `UpstreamMessageEvent`s.
- The try/finally construct is not actually necessary as Netty will catch any `Throwable`s and fire an ExceptionEvent, but it feels more idiomatic this way.

HTH

Comment: Are you using you own SessionScope that extends SimpleScope?

Comment: @jkj Yes, that is what my example assumes.

Comment: Nice work @ThomasDufour! The idea should also work for Netty 4.  However, if a user specifies an `EventExecutor` for a handler when setting up a pipeline, you'll have to set up the scope again because the event will be handed off to a different thread. (just like it is with `ExecutionHandler` in Netty 3.)

Comment: Thanks @TrustinLee, I've edited the answer to mention `ExecutionHandler` in the Netty 3 case.